# Numpy array: how to row-wise check if first X amount of values are valid?

Tags: python, numpy

### Problem Description

Consider the following two example arrays:

```
arr = np.array([
    [5.0, 2.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan],
    [9.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0],
    [4.0, 7.0, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan],
    [8.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.0]
])

amounts = np.array([
    3,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    0,
    5
])
```

For each row in array `arr` I would like to check if the first X entries in the row are not `NaN`, but all the other entries are `NaN`. This amount X is different for each row and is given by array `amounts`.

So my expected result would be the following boolean array:

```
array([ True, False, False, False,  True, False])
```

### Tried thus far

I managed to come up with the following working code:

```
result = []
for (row, amount) in zip(arr, amounts):
    if (~np.isnan(row)[:amount]).all() and np.isnan(row)[amount:].all():
        result.append(True)
    else:
        result.append(False)

result = np.array(result)
print(result)
```

Though this code produces the desired result, I have the feeling that it's still inefficient. I would suspect that a method without any for-loops is possible, but I haven't been able to find it yet.

Would anyone be able to help find a fully vectorized solution for this problem?

Comment: The second row is `False` - is this because it has a non-NaN value at the end?

Comment: @wwii Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = np.array([[5.0, 2.0, 1.0, np.nan, np.nan],
              [9.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.0],
              [4.0, 7.0, 4.0, np.nan, np.nan],
              [8.0, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
              [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
              [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 6.0]])

b = np.array([3,1,2,3,0,5])

c = np.logical_not(np.isnan(a))
firstn = b == c.argmin(axis=1)
no_extras = b == c.sum(axis=1)
result = np.logical_and(firstn,no_extras)
```

Make a boolean array of non-NaN values.

To ensure the the first `n` values meet the criteria; 
Use `numpy.argmin()` to find the first `NaN` - compare this with the `counts` array.

To ensure that there aren't any non-NaN values *after* the NaNs *start*;  Sum all the the `True`s row-wise in the boolean array, compare that to the `counts` array.

`and` both of those results.

Comment: Good solution. For the sake of interest and in the end of readability: why do you prefer numpy boolean functions over `~` and `and`? Makes this neat approach too verbose in my eyes.

Comment: To be candid, I really don't know but I have always preferred them to the *symbolic* version - maybe more explicit?. If you use the ufuncs there are some parameters you can use also.

Comment: Maybe because when I first started, I was conjuring straight from the docs and it just became a habit?

Answer (score 2):

You can try smth like this:

```
# Values are column numbers
grid = np.tile(np.arange(arr.shape[1]), (arr.shape[0], 1))

# Mask
mask = grid < amounts.reshape((-1, 1))

# Comparison
np.all(~np.isnan(arr) == mask, axis=1)
```